# How to create a ring tone of the music file imported from the music library

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to create a ring tone application, in which the user select a file from the music library, and import it to application, and after importing he will be able to create a ring tone of that music file. Any help will greatly be appreciated. because i am new to this field.

Comment: i am just asking the help, from which point i should start.

Comment: Click the link at the beginning of my post and reading; hopefully you'll understand the reasoning behind my comment,

Comment: sorry brother i was wrong. i have created the app, in which i an adding music files from the ipod music library, now i want to get a 40 second m4r file from that music file. i did not know how to do that.

Comment: @James: did you get the conversion working?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question over a very large topic, you may want to reduce it to bullet points as different questions.

You will need to start with specifying what kind of music files you will allow, .mp3, .ogg, .wav, flac, wma, etc. - each of these formats have different ways to break down music, you'll need to know each one that you're planning to allow. It's a very large subject - you could try licensing software like: http://www.avs4you.com/AVS-Audio-Editor.aspx and writing extensions on it that will automatically allow a user to to choose 'break points' or have your software attempt to find them yourself.

Comment: i want to create an app like "Ringtone Maker".

Comment: yah, you're not going to get an answer better than this over stackoverflow.